# Sea Monster 5 installation

Tags: 16.04

Can anybody help me installing Sea Monster 5 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS? I downloaded it from sourceforge.net and after unpacking the archive I cannot go further. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/projects/seamonster/postdownload?source=dlp let's you download the PDF with instructions. What exactly is the issue?

Comment: The pdf is for windows version installation

Comment: Please post the output of `ls /path/to/<your unpacked folder>`...

Comment: *The pdf is for windows version installation* No, it doesn't matter because it's a Java program. As long as you have the proper Java support already installed, the OS is pretty much irrelevant.

Comment: This is the output in the installation folder: cristian@ubuntu:~/Downloads/SeaMonster$ ls
about_files  about.html  artifacts.xml  configuration  libcairo-swt.so  p2  plugins  SeaMonster  SeaMonster.ini
cristian@ubuntu:~/Downloads/SeaMonster$

Answer (score 0):

1. Due to oldness of SeaMonster 5, it was compiled for 32-bit, so you need to install 32-bit Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on the VM for testing
2. Install Java

   ```
   sudo apt-get install default-jre
   ```
3. Download linux version of SeaMonster 5

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads
   wget https://netcologne.dl.sourceforge.net/project/seamonster/SeaMonster%205/SeaMonster5_linux.gtk.x86.zip
   ```
4. Unzip it, set executable, launch it:

   ```
   unzip SeaMonster5_linux.gtk.x86.zip
   cd SeaMonster/
   chmod +x SeaMonster
   ./SeaMonster
   ```
5. Get splash screen and enjoy!

[image: SeaMonster 5 splash screen]